# ALTER TABLE does not allow Foreign Key creation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, foreign-key-relationship, alter-table

So I was trying to set a column as the primary key and was getting some errors as I tried to set it as NOT NULL in the import wizard. One fix I saw was using the ALTER TABLE statement to change that column to not allow null values( so it can be the primary key). It turned out it was a stupid mistake and I was setting the wrong column as the primary key. Easy fix. Just deleted the table and imported it correctly. Now that I have all my data imported, whenever I try to set the Foreign Key relationship I get this message when I try to save:

> 'Student Contact' table saved successfully 'Student Event Attendance'
>   table
>   - Unable to create relationship 'FK_Student Event Attendance_Student Contact'.   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY
>   constraint "FK_Student Event Attendance_Student Contact". The conflict
>   occurred in database "Student Archive", table "dbo.Student Contact",
>   column 'Student Record ID'.

I have 3 tables:

```
Student Contact (Student Record ID (pk)), 
Student Event Attendance(FairRsvp Record ID(pk), Student Record ID(fk)), and 
Student Observation (Student Observation ID(pk),Student Record ID(fk))
```

Even when I have deleted the whole database and re-imported the excel files I still get this problem because of the ALTER TABLE statement. How can I get rid of this? If I can delete the whole thing and start from scratch that would be easiest since I do not have much data.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you share the column definitions for the relevant tables, please?

Comment: The ALTER TABLE statement was ALTER TABLE [Student Event Attendance]
ADD [CareerFair Event ID] float NOT NULL

Comment: I believe that's what it was. This was a few days ago and I'm picking the project back up

Comment: If there are rows in table, you can't add a column not acepting null values. Try:
`ALTER TABLE [Student Event Attendance] ADD [CareerFair Event ID] float NULL `

Comment: I was able to work out that issue and that was a mistake I made while importing the data. The problem I have now is that original ALTER TABLE statement I made is not allowing me to create the foreign key relationships. I want to undo or get rid of that ALTER TABLE statement if at all possible

Comment: If you deleted and recreated the database, the `ALTER TABLE` statement you ran previously isn't affecting anything. If you mean the line in the error statement, it's almost certainly talking about the `ALTER TABLE` statement that's used when adding the foreign key. That's why I asked for your column definitions - it sounds like there's a problem with how you're defining your foreign key.